# Calling child class constructor inside generic method possible?

Tags: c#, class, generics, inheritance, constructor

So, i have this code:

```
public class Fruit {
    public Fruit() {
         // base class constructor
    }            
}
public class Apple: Fruit {
    public Fruit(): base() {
          // child class constructor
    }

}


T MakeNew<T>(T  item) where T: Fruit, new() {

     T tempNewClass = new T();
     return tempNewClass;

}
```

And then, in my program:

```
Apple apple = new Apple();
Apple anotherApple = MakeNew<Apple>(apple);
```

Why anotherApple is of Apple class, but during creation inside my method, only base constructor is called, as if it was treated as base class only?

I am guessing, thats because new() keyword on method init line.

Is there a way to create child class inside generic method and invoke it's constructor?

PS: Please, I am learning C#, and trying my best to get all answers I need from internet. I am stumbling with this problem since 4 days now, and didn't find working answer anywhere else. But I can be wrong, maybe I am just asking wrong question?

Answer (score 0):

You may just be noticing that the base class constructor is always called before the sub class. Try running the code below to observe the behavior:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("new Apple()");
        Apple apple = new Apple();

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("MakeNew<Apple>(apple)");
        Apple anotherApple = MakeNew<Apple>(apple);
    }

    static private T MakeNew<T>(T item) where T: Fruit, new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
    public class Fruit
    {
        public Fruit()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fruit Constructor");
        }
    }

    public class Apple : Fruit
    {
        public Apple() : base()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Apple Constructor");
        }
    }
}
```